# how to use css to float the div from bottom left to top right when reduce the windows screen size

Tags: css, html

I would like to know if I can float the div like this using CSS. What I would like to do is to move the DIV which is CSS DIV 2 under the CSS DIV 1 to the right when reducing the windows size.  See the screenshot below:

This is how three DIV would display on bigger windows size. First DIV is at the top left corner, the second DIV is under the first DIV. Then the third DIV is on the top right.

[image: Normal Look for three DIV]

When I resize the browser windows, the third DIV which has wider width will drop to the botton under the first DIV, and the second DIV will automatcially move to the top right corner to fill in the space.
[image: After resize the browser windows]

Anyone think that this is possible to do it by using CSS, and might not need to use JS or others?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that change is achieved either by changing from a columnar layout to a row layout, or else by swapping the order of the two  elements. Either way, it requires JavaScript.

Comment: Do you know how to use JavaScript to achieve this?